# Rails - Where would a batch record updater go?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-view-controller

This might be a noob-ish question, but it has been on my mind for a few day now, and I can't seem to find a "proper" solution for this.

So I wrote a batch updater for a client, and it is just sitting in a controller. Where would I put the code if I am to move it out of the controller? The batch updater is updating multiple models.

Thanks for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class like `BatchUpdater` or just `Form` and call it from controller